# How to launch specific android activity from app with autostart at boot?

Tags: android, android-activity, tablet, autostart

i have an issue with launching an specific android activity (not the Main one), with autostart at boot from an android app. I have activity A which is the Main one and has a GUI, and i have an activity B which has no GUI, i need to run activity B periodically to check for updates and then show a notification, which when is clicked launches activity A, but i don't know exactly where the autostart would go. Could some one help me on this? thanks.

Comment: Why not create a BroadcastReceiver that will be triggered whenever the device starts. Check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED

Comment: I had a confusion about the BroadcastReceiver, you are right, i can specify the Activity no matter if is not the main one, i learned a lot now. Thanks.